# Using 2 payment processors with Webform CIVI intergration

Tags: webform-civicrm, payment-processor

I want the user to choose between two payment processors in a webform with CIVI integration. I can let the user select between PayPal and direct debit. However I want to set the value based on country. So if the user is not in the United Kingdom, payment processor is set to PayPal. However when it comes to setting conditionals, I don't know what the values of the payment processor is.

I've tried values 0, 1, 2 - i've tried the value 12 from the CIVICRM admin payment processor page, but nothing works. I've also tried just typing in PayPal Standard.

Any ideas?

CIVICRM 4.6.33 - Drupal 7

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can find out the values of any field by looking at the markup. If you visit your webform and right-click the payment processor field, select "inspect element" (if you're using a decent webbrowser) it will show you the code.

```
<option value="0">Pay Later</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Test Processor</option>
```

So in this example the test processor has a value of 1, pay later has a value of 0.