# Two payment processors options on one webform

Tags: webform-civicrm, payment-processor, recurring-contributions

Different payment processors offer different options that we would like to have available from a single form. Is it possible to have different payment processors engaged from different form options on the same form? So e.g. if you select a recurring payment the form uses GoCardless, and otherwise it uses Paypal?

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple payment processor on a contribution or membership or event registration online forms. However the user will need to manually select which payment processor he would like to choose or you can add custom javascript to hide payment processor selection and set the payment process based on the selection of recurring option or membership they choose. This is same on offline forms as well.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: The question is tagged webform-civicrm, could you extend your answer to cover that? Related: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21269/using-2-payment-processors-with-webform-civi-intergration.